# logback slf4j unable to get log statements in log file

Tags: slf4j, logback

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                                                  -->
<configuration>
<!-- Errors were reported during translation. -->
<!-- No root logger configuration was found -->

 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>


<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
<file>c:\log\test.log</file>
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
<pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>  

 <logger name="com.base22" level="DEBUG" />
<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> 
</root>
 </configuration>
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>


 <dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>0.9.26</version>
 </dependency>

  <dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
<version>0.9.26</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
<version>0.9.26</version>
 </dependency>
```

Using above configurations for logback.....log statements are being displayed on console but test.log is not created and I dnt find any logs even in the file after me creating the file..do I need to write any other configurations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logback.xml is not placed where logback looks for it, so it silently falls back to a "print to console" configuration.

See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html for all the details about the configuration mechanism.

Comment: i got it thanks a lot i was placing the file under WEB-INF because of which it wasn't working